# Show form results without reload in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a page with a form I'd like to see the results of without reloading in my rails app, but I'm new to incorporating JS in ruby on rails. I've tried following along [Display result data without page refresh on form submission in ruby on rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11304989/display-result-data-without-page-refresh-on-form-submission-in-ruby-on-rails) as well as a few 'intro to AJAX' guides, but am struggling to apply them to my own project.

In my user profile `profile.html.erb`, I have a list of tags for a review

```
<% if review.tags.length > 0 %>
  <% review.tags.each do |tag| %>
    <%= tag.category %>
    <%= tag.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Under which there's a form to add a new tag

```
<%= simple_form_for @tag, url: "/add_tag/#{review.id}" do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :category %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

(I'm currently using the gem simple_form for formating reasons. It's not the cause of my confusion, though I think I might need to remove it to apply a solution)

This form submits to my `reviews_controller`, which has this method `add_tag`

```
def add_tag
  @review = Review.find_by(id: params[:id])
  tag_cat = params[:tag][:category]
  tag_name = params[:tag][:name]
    
  if valid_tag(tag_cat, tag_name) && tag_cat != ""
    @tag = grab_tag(tag_cat, tag_name)
    if ReviewTag.find_by(tag_id: @tag.id, review_id: @review.id).nil?
      ReviewTag.create(tag_id: @tag.id, review_id: @review.id)
    end
    redirect_to '/profile'
  else
    redirect_to '/profile'
  end
end
```

The `redirect_to /profile` works just fine at the moment, though it seems I need to use `format.js` in some way instead? I'm struggling to see what changes I need to make on the javascript and view side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you try fill form data and save it in one action. If i am right understand you issue you have `Review` and `Review` has many review tags. And you try added this tags on page where you working with `Review` model and you want edit `Review` data and `ReviewTag` data on one page without reloading. You need to use [`nested_attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.3.1/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) and create form how edited `ReviewTag` from javascript. Recomend to see this guide https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-on-rails-nested-attributes

It works like this:

1. on `Review` model add `accepts_nested_attributes_for :review_tags`
2. on page where you edit `Review` model added block like `form.fields_for :review_tags do |builder|`
3. on the same page added a button like `create tag` and added js `onclick` action - this action create a form for new `ReviewTag`. Read this - [How to Create a Form Dynamically Via Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964927/how-to-create-a-form-dynamically-via-javascript)

If you need to validate you new tag dynamicly you can call ajax for do it

Comment: I'm actually just adding a single `ReviewTag` to a preexisting `Review`, but this is close enough to clear up what I needed, especially as I think I have somewhere else I'll be using `nested_attributes` now, thanks!